# SQL Using Distinct returning Duplicates records

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I am trying to execute following query. I a expecting no duplicates should be come. but in the result set i am getting duplicates records. I am new to sql.

```
SELECT DISTINCT pr.id as ruleid, pr.alias as rulename,grp.id as groupId, grp.alias, fgp.filterGroupType FROM  ProcessingService s    INNER JOIN s.fileGroupingParameter fgp ON fgp.status =:fileGroupStatus INNER JOIN s.svcPathList path ON path.status =:pathStatus  INNER JOIN path.policy p  ON p.status =:policyStatus  INNER JOIN p.policyGroupRelSet pgr  INNER JOIN pgr.group grp ON grp.status =:groupStatus  INNER JOIN grp.policyGroupRuleRelSet rr  INNER JOIN rr.policyRule pr  ON pr.status =:ruleStatus  INNER JOIN pr.policyActionSet pa ON pa.status =:actionStatus WHERE s.id in (:idList) AND pa.action =:actionType AND s.status =:serviceStatus AND fgp.filterGroupType ='Rulewise' AND pr.category =:reasonCategory AND pr.severity =:reasonSeverity
```

how i can get distinct records as per my requirement.

The result set I am getting is

```
"policy rule1"   
"policy rule1"  
"policy rule12"  
"policy rule12"
```

and I want:

```
"policy rule1"  
"policy rule12"
```

as output.

Comment: Then select only needed columns if you include other as well then distinct will be applied on whole row not on column

Comment: Very strange, your query selects many columns, but you say the result only contains one column.